# AOSP Dual Monitor Support at Conflicting Aspect Ratios

Tags: android, screen, android-source, hdmi, android-hardware

I am creating an In-Vehicle Infotainment (IVI) system running Android. The development board I am using is the Rock960 from 96boards.com This board supports dual display output which is perfect because it needs to drive both the Head Unit (HU) and the Instrument Cluster (IC) in front of the driver. This is where the issue lies. The HU has a resolution of 1920x1080 and the IC has a resolution of 1280x480. Output works on both displays, but it appears very stretched on the IC due to its odd resolution.

The SoC is RK3399 from Rockchip. Here is a link to the AOSP page for this board: https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/rock/build/aosp.md.html

I have tried changing the framebuffer resolution: persist.sys.framebuffer.main=1280x480 in device/rockchip/rk3399/rk3399_box/system.prop

When I do that, everything displays correctly on the IC but then the HU appears stretched.

Here is the system properties file:

```
#
# system.prop
#

#rild.libpath=/system/lib/libreference-ril.so
#rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyUSB2
# Default ecclist
ro.ril.ecclist=112,911
wifi.interface=wlan0
persist.tegra.nvmmlite = 1
persist.sys.boot.check=false
ro.audio.monitorOrientation=true

#NFC
debug.nfc.fw_download=false
debug.nfc.se=false

#add Rockchip properties here
ro.rk.screenoff_time=2147483647
ro.rk.screenshot_enable=true
ro.rk.def_brightness=200
ro.rk.homepage_base=http://www.google.com/webhp?client= 
{CID}&amp;source=android-home
ro.rk.install_non_market_apps=false
sys.hwc.compose_policy=6
sys.wallpaper.rgb565=0
sf.power.control=8847360
sys.rkadb.root=0
ro.sf.fakerotation=false
ro.sf.hwrotation=0
ro.rk.MassStorage=false
ro.rk.systembar.voiceicon=true
ro.rk.systembar.tabletUI=false
ro.rk.LowBatteryBrightness=true
ro.tether.denied=false
sys.resolution.changed=false
ro.default.size=100
persist.sys.timezone=
ro.product.usbfactory=rockchip_usb
ro.support.lossless.bitstream=true
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=15
ro.factory.tool=0
#set default lcd density for rk3399 box product
ro.sf.lcd_density=213
ro.adb.secure =0
ro.rk.statusbar=0
# set to false if not use displayd
ro.rk.displayd.enable=false

# default main framebuffer resolution
persist.sys.framebuffer.main=1920x1080

# default primary display
sys.hwc.device.primary=DP
sys.hwc.device.extend=HDMI-A
```

Also, any idea what ro.rk.displayd.enable is?

I expect both displays to show their content correctly according to their own resolutions. The output should not be stretched or distorted on either screen.

Answer (score 1):

see [HWComposer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer.cpp); this should be `primary` & `external` - instead of `primary` and `extend` (where `extend` might cause the scaling); which might already answer the question. these should be defined in `/kernel/drivers/video/rockchip`. adding further logging to the source code might help to understand what is even going on, when it is setting up the displays.

`displayd` might be an `OSD` display daemon, hence anything which ends with a `d` is usually a daemon. if this can be somehow be done with Android, while the kernel is adequately configured, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation

the most easy might be to [ask them](http://rock-chips.com/a/en/contact/index.html) (at least, compared to Chinese manuals).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try this as soon as I am home from work. Also, For my reference, any idea what source file **persist.sys.framebuffer.main** refers to?

Comment: @C.Hochstedler this might be the frame-buffer device for the primary display port.

Comment: So, is there a way I can find out if there is a similar property such as **persist.sys.framebuffer.external**, or something of that sort? I have done countless searches with no luck.

Comment: @C.Hochstedler run `adb shell getprop` to get a list of all that is available. all these `ro.rk` are vendor specific properties; eg. `adb shell getprop | grep ro.rk`. while the `HDMI` is configured to `extend` the primary `DP` display, it will scale unless they both have the same resolution. no clue where this is defined; only know that it should be set up as `external`... just alike one would do it with a notebook and a beamer, for presentation purposes. the `HUD` is in principle quite similar to that.

Comment: beside the kernel configuration, ordinary one can set the resolution: `Settings > HDMI > HDMI Resolution`.